# long running loops becomes non-debuggable in intellij

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, hotswap

I use IntelliJ to develop and debug applications.  Many times I hot-swap classes as part of debugging. Some time (just sometimes) I am unable to set break points in newly added code. The IDE shows that the break point is valid-- but does not stop there.

I observed that this happens with loops that ran many many times. Any one faced similar problem? How can I fix this?

(Intellj8, JDK 1.6.x)

Comment: Maybe, it's better to provide some code sample. I mean loop and breakpoint position/condition.

Answer (score 0):

Place a breakpoint where the many times running loop is and restart the test.